# why creating table with my dbform sometimes doesn't have result in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet between the JSP and the database that performs the database operations on the user's behalf, marshal the response into request or session scope, and stream the response to the page that needed to be displayed.

In the JSP, the form includes all the input fields and the submit one. 
The form is created properly with dbform but the table that I tried to create in mysql as if becomes vanished.
Why creating table for my dbform sometimes losses tables in mysql database?
how can I resolve the problem? or how can I check the source of error?

part of code in jsp page is as such:

```
if("CreateTable".equals(request.getParameter("dbform1"))){
String CreateSQL="";

command cmdformdata = new command();
cmdformdata.dbURL=(String)session.getAttribute("connection");
cmdformdata.sqlText="SELECT * from forms "
        + " WHERE  (formId = ?)";
param p1fd = new param();
p1fd.setVal(request.getParameter("formDDL"));
cmdformdata.params.add(p1fd);
ResultSet formdata = cmdformdata.execute();
if(formdata.next())
    CreateSQL += "CREATE TABLE "+formdata.getString("formTitle") + " ("
          + "PK bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,";  


command cmd = new command();
cmd.dbURL=(String)session.getAttribute("connection");
cmd.sqlText="SELECT forms.formTitle,formfield.fieldTitle FROM "
        + " formfield   INNER JOIN forms ON (formfield.formId = forms.formId)"
        + " WHERE   (sourceFormId IS NULL) AND   (formfield.formId = ?)";
param p1 = new param();
p1.setVal(request.getParameter("formDDL"));
cmd.params.add(p1);
ResultSet r = cmd.execute();

while(r.next()){
    CreateSQL += r.getString("fieldTitle")+ " text ,";
}
CreateSQL += "username text ,"
        + "HjDate bigint(20),"
         + "formId bigint(20),"
        + "fieldRow int(11),"
        + "PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),UNIQUE KEY `PK` (`PK`) )"
        + "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;";
command CreateTablecmd = new command();
CreateTablecmd.dbURL=(String)session.getAttribute("connection");
CreateTablecmd.sqlText=CreateSQL;
CreateTablecmd.executeUpdate();
```

}

Comment: I'm really not a pro with JSP/Servlet, but when I debug the code objects being added to the dropdownList. may its problem is from `param p1 = new param();
p1.setVal(request.getParameter("formDDL"));
cmd.params.add(p1);
ResultSet r = cmd.execute();`?

Comment: print out CreateSQL and execute it in mysql to make sure everything is ok with syntax

Comment: Thank you, Your comment helped me to resolve the problem. In my fields I had a ">" character that was not supported in mySql