# what is the difference with "test" javascript variable and "#test" variable can i convert var javascript to "#test"

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp

I've seen a servlet between the JSP and the database that is implemented similar [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901363/why-creating-table-with-my-dbform-sometimes-doesnt-have-result-in-jsp). the important part for me is this:

```
param p1fd = new param();
p1fd.setVal(request.getParameter("formDDL"));
```

where the parameter in jsp code is referenced as "#formDDL"

the problem is that I have formDDL as a javascript variable as such:

```
var formDDL;
```

How can I convert the javascript variable to #formDDL?

Is there any other way to I pass this variable to Expression Language written for inserting in mySQL code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scriptlet part of the JSP is executed on the server side prior to it being returned to the client. Therefore you can't change its value after the page is sent to the client. You would have to have a preliminary page that sets the value of formDDL in javascript and then call into the server to request the page with the formDDL included as a request parameter or POST data. Basically the same approach that was done in the page you linked.

If you didn't want to have to fully reload the page to change the value of formDDL then you would have to take a completely different approach and look into using Ajax.

Also be mindful of SQL injection attacks when following a similar approach to the one you linked to.

Comment: thank you; actually I had a big code with server side, too. but I was going away from working with it. Now, I am convinced to working on it